# Best practice for (CMake) project structure?

Tags: git, cmake

I have implemented a library that, in addition to the actual code, also contains a folder for unit tests and one for examples. Also, this library uses spdlog internally and a proprietary library.
Currently my CMake project structure looks like this:

```
myLib
  |-- CMakeLists.txt
  |-- src/ (The actual lib target)
    |-- CMakeLists.txt
    |-- code etc.
  |-- examples/ 
    |-- CMakeLists.txt
    |-- code etc.
  |-- test/ (unit tests) 
    |-- CMakeLists.txt
    |-- code etc.
  |-- googletest/ (git submodule)
    |-- CMakeLists.txt
    |-- code etc.
  |-- spdlog/ (git submodule)
    |-- CMakeLists.txt
    |-- code etc.
  |-- proprietaryLib/ (git submodule)
    |-- CMakeLists.txt
    |-- code etc.
```

On its own, this works fine. But if I want to include myLib in an application that also uses googletest and spdlog, for example, it gets messy. Then I can either use the corresponding sources from myLib or I have the modules twice. Both I do not find very nice.

I already thought about making a project only for the lib and a second one for examples/test in which I include the lib as a submodule and link the additional libs (spdlog/proprietaryLib) to it. I could then do the same in the application.

Another approach would be to evaluate in the top CMake if it is the top level project or if it was included via add_subdirectory() and then decide if the subdirectories should be included.

Which solution would you prefer? Are there other/better ones?

Comment: Dependent submodules could be included by their consumers via [FetchContent](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/FetchContent.html). That approach is similar to `add_subdirectory` but guarantees that a submodule will be included only once. While FetchContent usually has a download step, you could easily use it with already "downloaded" submodules: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74123491/cmake-alternate-option-to-fetchcontent-when-the-source-file-already-exists-loc/74127927#74127927

Comment: If you've got a lib that gets updated extremely rarely you may want to assume it's preinstalled and use `find_package`. At least for gtest there's a cmake configuration available and it you're dealing with a lib where it isn't, you could provide your own find module. This way every project using `find_package(<dependency>)` will get the same version of the lib. You may need to add a bootstrap step to your build process where you create and compile the cmake projects for dependencies and install them to a local folder (`cmake --install ... --prefix dependency_root`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested by fabian I installed gtest/spdlog on my system instead of adding them as submodules and added the following to my top CMakeLists.txt:

```
find_package(GTest REQUIRED)
find_package(spdlog REQUIRED)
```

And this to the src/CMakeLists.txt:

```
target_link_libraries(myLib PRIVATE spdlog::spdlog)
```

It works. Thanks a lot!